# Which hash code hash map implementation uses for value retrieval

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, hashcode

I know that hashmap actually uses hashcode  to store and retrive object from hashtable but my doupt is which hashcode it uses. map actually contains hashcode for key and hashcode for its value. let's consider this way

```
Map<String,String> student=new HashMap();
student.put("name", "foo");
System.out.println("name".hashCode());
System.out.println("foo".hashCode());
```

In here hashcode for name(key) is 3373707
hashcode for foo(value) is 101574

my doupt is which one it should use to store and retrive object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see from the following code in `HashMap`, it uses its own hash function:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    return putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, true);
}

static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

It uses the object's `hashCode`, but `xor`s it and arithmetically shifts it to the right 16 times.

To answer your question specifically, it uses the `hashCode` of the key and **not** the value.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Oh I see, if you have any more questions, feel free to ask me!  And thank you :)

Comment: definitely i will